# Same Origin Policy with My REST API

Tags: php, javascript, api, rest

I would like to know what solution I can use in order to have a REST api with js as the client and php as the server side of the api?
I have tried using iFrame, channel files and custom headers.
But none has worked.
- I would like to know how I should do it.
Thanks in advance.

Things I have tried already:
**1)iFrame:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#fff").contents().find("#rrr").submit();
})(jQuery);
-------------
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
  <iframe id="fff" src="#">
    hi
    <form id="rrr" action="http://mydomain/rest/rest.php" method="get">
      <input type="text" value="testy" name="check" />
    </form>
  </iframe>
</body>
```

-->returns nothing.

**2) Channel file:**
file on server(js):(conjs.js)

```
 function getDev(callback){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'rest.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'name=John', // or $('#myform').serializeArray()
        success: function(data) { 
            callback('Get completed '+data); 
        }
    });
}
------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
  <script src="http://mydomain/rest/conjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
getDev(function (response) {
    alert(response);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

-->returns nothing.

**3)Php headers:**

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
    case 'http://jsbin.com': case 'https://jsbin.com':
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    break;
}
```

-->returns nothing.

None has worked so far.

Comment: The only real solution is a proxy hosted on your server that forwards the requests server-side to the other api (jsbin), and returns the results.  This is also more secure.

Comment: @mellamokb are you sure? because this makes it more difficult for users, how does the facebook js sdk do it then?

Comment: I misunderstood what you are doing.  You're providing a js api for 3-rd party users? Then you need JSONP or IFrame embedding.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007018/why-does-new-facebook-javascript-sdk-not-violate-the-same-origin-policy.

Comment: @mellamokb thanks, I wish I could tick your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) would help. A reverse proxy is used to get around the same origin policy by making it look like the request came from the same server.